# OpenGL send color to shader

Tags: c++, opengl, colors, buffer

I'm following the tutorials from: http://www.opengl-tutorial.org and trying a few things by my self.

At the moment my program can create triangles as class objects, transform their size and positions, and animate them (very simple code I just play around with). But when I'm trying to pass color value with Buffer Array to the Shaders, my triangles are not rendering.

I'll pass the relevant code here and try to make it understandble, hope someone can help me out here!

CODE:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iomanip>

#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtx/transform.hpp>

using namespace glm;

#include "loadShader.h"
#include "model.h"

int _screenWidth = 1024;
int _screenHeight = 768;



int main()
{

    //START GLFW
    if (!glfwInit())
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLFW\n");
        return -1;
    }

    //GLFW SETTINGS
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4); //4x antialiasing
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3); //OPENGL 3.3
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE); //Mac compatible?
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE); 

    //open window                                                              
    GLFWwindow* window;
    window = glfwCreateWindow(_screenWidth, _screenHeight, "Tutorial 01", NULL, NULL);
    if (window == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open GLFW window. Make sure your GPU is openGL 3.3 compatible!\n");
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);


    //INITIALIZE GLEW
    glewExperimental = true; //needed in core profile

    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLEW.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    // Ensure we can capture the escape key being pressed below
    glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_STICKY_KEYS, GL_TRUE);

    glClearColor(0.125f, 0.0f, 0.3725f, 0.0f);

    //Enable Depth test
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);


    GLuint VertexArrayID;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VertexArrayID);
    glBindVertexArray(VertexArrayID);

    // Create and compile GLSL program from the shaders
    GLuint programID = LoadShaders("Shaders/vertexShaders.vert", "Shaders/fragmentShaders.frag");
    //get handle for MVP uniform
    GLuint MatrixID = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "MVP");


    /////////////////////
    //MODEL//////////////
    /////////////////////
    //two triangles
    int nVertices = 6;
    //created through model class
    model object1, object2;
    object1.createTriangle();
    object2.createTriangle();

    //initialize buffer data arrays
    GLfloat g_vertex_buffer_data[12*3];    

    // One color for each vertex
    static const GLfloat g_color_buffer_data[] = {
        0.583f,  0.771f,  0.014f,
        0.609f,  0.115f,  0.436f,
        0.327f,  0.483f,  0.844f,
        0.822f,  0.569f,  0.201f,
        0.435f,  0.602f,  0.223f,
        0.310f,  0.747f,  0.185f };

    //////////////////////////
    //////////////////////////
    //////////////////////////

    //CREATE BUFFER
    //This will identify our vertex and color buffer
    GLuint vertexbuffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexbuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);

    GLuint colorbuffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &colorbuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorbuffer);

    //counters
    float time          = 0.0f;
    int counter         = 0;
    int counterStep     = 100;


    do {

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        time        = time + 0.01;
        counter     = counter + 1;


        //TRANSFORM MY TRIANGLES (its working)
        glm::vec3 rotationAxis(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        glm::vec3 translation(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.025f);
        float rotationAngle = 0.25f;

        object1.rotate(rotationAngle, rotationAxis);
        //object2.rotate(0.5*rotationAngle, rotationAxis);
        object1.translate(translation);

        //Update coordinates in vertex buffer (both triangles)
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            g_vertex_buffer_data[i * 3]         = object1.transformedPosition[i].x;
            g_vertex_buffer_data[i * 3 + 1]     = object1.transformedPosition[i].y;
            g_vertex_buffer_data[i * 3 + 2]     = object1.transformedPosition[i].z;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            g_vertex_buffer_data[i * 3 + 9]     = object2.transformedPosition[i].x;
            g_vertex_buffer_data[i * 3 + 10]    = object2.transformedPosition[i].y;
            g_vertex_buffer_data[i * 3 + 11]    = object2.transformedPosition[i].z;
        }


        //Model matrix
        glm::mat4 modelM = glm::mat4(1.0f);

        //Projection matrix:
        glm::mat4 projectionM = glm::perspective(45.0f, 4.0f / 3.0f, 0.1f, 100.0f);
        //Camera matrix:
        glm::mat4 viewM = lookAt(
            glm::vec3(8, 2, 2+10*time),
            glm::vec3(0, 0, 0),
            glm::vec3(0, 1, 0));

        //MODEL VIEW PROJECTION MATRIX:
        glm::mat4 mvpM = projectionM * viewM * modelM;

        //Give our vertices and colors to OpenGL
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(g_vertex_buffer_data), g_vertex_buffer_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(g_color_buffer_data), g_color_buffer_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        /////////////////////////////////////////////

        //USE SHADERS
        glUseProgram(programID);

        //Send our transformation to the currently bound shader, MVP uniform
        glUniformMatrix4fv(MatrixID, 1, 0, &mvpM[0][0]);

        //1rst attribute buffer: vertices
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
        glVertexAttribPointer(
            0,          //attribute 0, no particular reason, but must match the layout in the shader
            3,          //size
            GL_FLOAT,   //type
            GL_FALSE,   //normalized?
            0,          //stride
            (void*)0    //array buffer offset
            );

        //2nd attribute buffer: colors
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorbuffer);
        glVertexAttribPointer(
            1,          //attribute number
            3,          //size
            GL_FLOAT,   //type
            GL_FALSE,   //normalized?
            0,          //stride
            (void*)0    //array buffer offset
            );


        //Draw the triangle
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, nVertices); //Starting from vertex 0; 3 vertices total
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);


        // Swap buffers
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();

    }


    // Check if the ESC key was pressed or the window was closed
    while (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) != GLFW_PRESS &&
        glfwWindowShouldClose(window) == 0);




    // Cleanup VBO
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &vertexbuffer);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &colorbuffer);
    glDeleteProgram(programID);
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VertexArrayID);

    // Close OpenGL window and terminate GLFW
    glfwTerminate();



    return 0;
}
```

Vertexshader:

```
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) in vec3 vertexPosition_modelspace;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 vertexColor;

uniform mat4 MVP;

out vec3 fragmentColor;

void main(){
    gl_Position = MVP * vec4(vertexPosition_modelspace,1.0);
    fragmentColor = vertexColor;
}
```

Fragmentshder:

```
#version 330 core

in vec3 fragmentColor;
out vec3 color;


void main(){

    color = fragmentColor;
}
```

If I remove:

```
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(g_color_buffer_data), g_color_buffer_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

and:

```
        //2nd attribute buffer: colors
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorbuffer);
        glVertexAttribPointer(
            1,          //attribute number
            3,          //size
            GL_FLOAT,   //type
            GL_FALSE,   //normalized?
            0,          //stride
            (void*)0    //array buffer offset
            );
```

from the main function, the triangles renders.

**EDIT**
Here is only the relevant code which is where I think there is a problem:

```
    //FIRST DO THIS: (but not sure why..)
    GLuint VertexArrayID;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VertexArrayID);
    glBindVertexArray(VertexArrayID);

    //initialize buffer data arrays
    GLfloat g_vertex_buffer_data[]  = { something };
    GLfloat g_color_buffer_data[]   = { something };

    //CREATE BUFFER
    GLuint vertexbuffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexbuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);

    GLuint colorbuffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &colorbuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorbuffer);

    //LOOP
    do {

        //UPDATE BUFFER DATA
        GLfloat g_vertex_buffer_data[]  = { something new };
        GLfloat g_color_buffer_data[]   = { something new };

        //SEND NEW BUFFER DATA TO SHADERS
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(g_vertex_buffer_data), g_vertex_buffer_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(g_color_buffer_data), g_color_buffer_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        //USE SHADERS
        glUseProgram(programID);

        //1rst attribute buffer: vertices positions
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
        glVertexAttribPointer(
            0,          //attribute 0, no particular reason, but must match the layout in the shader
            3,          //size
            GL_FLOAT,   //type
            GL_FALSE,   //normalized?
            0,          //stride
            (void*)0    //array buffer offset
            );

            //2nd attribute buffer: colors
            glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
            glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorbuffer);
            glVertexAttribPointer(
                1,          //attribute number
                3,          //size
                GL_FLOAT,   //type
                GL_FALSE,   //normalized?
                0,          //stride
                (void*)0    //array buffer offset
                );

        //Draw the triangles
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, nVertices); //Starting from vertex 0; 3 vertices total
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);

        // Swap buffers
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();

    }


    // Check if the ESC key was pressed or the window was closed
    while (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) != GLFW_PRESS &&
        glfwWindowShouldClose(window) == 0);




    // Cleanup VBO
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &vertexbuffer);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &colorbuffer);
    glDeleteProgram(programID);
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VertexArrayID);

    // Close OpenGL window and terminate GLFW
    glfwTerminate();

    return 0;
}
```

**SOLUTION**

I sort off solved my problem by looking at this tutorial https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Tutorial2%3a_VAOs,_VBOs,_Vertex_and_Fragment_Shaders_%28C_/_SDL%29 .

Basically I just moved the bufferBinding and bufferData functions outside the loop. Somehow that was ok before with the vertex positions, but not the vertex colors...

I read and learned more and changed some of the code and it's working now and I'm happy with it now:)

Comment: have a look at [complete GL+VAO/VBO+GLSL+shaders example in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31913542/2521214) and try if it works on your setup. if not there may be problem with gfx driver or with some of your libs. If it works then try to find the difference (sorry too lazy to compare so much code ...)

Answer (score 2):

Before you bufferdata, you should bind the buffer that you want send data in.

it should be

```
 glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer); 
 glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(g_vertex_buffer_data), g_vertex_buffer_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
 glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorbuffer);
 glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(g_color_buffer_data), g_color_buffer_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

Your code send did,not send any data to vertex position buffer.

Ps. for efficiency you should generate buffer, and submit the data before the loop.

Comment: Ok, thanks, let me check that.
So even if the vertices position are changing during the loop (animating), I don't need to call glBufferData(..) in the loop to let the shaders know I changed something? (If that makes sence)

Comment: if you do need change the vertex individually, you need call glbufferdata() in the loop.  But in most case, a simple uniform transformation is enough.

Comment: Even for animating mesh, the typical way is do vertex skinning, use an array of matrix to generate animation.  But still, it's up to you, just remember the cost for transfer data from cpu to gpu is Non-trivial

Comment: Ok,I have just been thinking that every transformation in the vertex shader affects the whole seen (move the camera and move the world).
But let's say I have 5 triangles moving around, how do I transform each their positions idenpendtly in the vertex shader?